# GOCAD and SKUA 3D Models Online

Tags: web-mapping, 3d, arcgis-server

I am looking to build a 3D Web Mapping Application using data/projects initially created within GOCAD and SKUA. We currently use ArcServer 10. Initial looking around online has suggested that I could export the GOCAD and SKUA data as TINs, importing the data into ArcGlobe and then serving it out via ArcServer.

It seems as if this is way too easy and could not possibly handle the geological layers within the data. Does anyone know of an alternative method?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at SkylineGlobe? TerraExplorer Pro can read many different types of data, models, you just require a good database to start with, *.mpt. Then you have the advantage of sharing your output online via Terrgate, so the world can see it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a software called GST which was initially developed at the TU Berakademie Freiberg in the scope of an EU Project: [ProMine](http://promine.gtk.fi). GST actually provides a database which can allows several 3D modeling tools to work together. But GST also provides a web frontend where the stored models can be watched from anywhere.

There are some [demos](https://demo.giga-infosystems.com) and implementations available:

- Geomodels of Bavaria: https://3dportal.lfu.bayern.de
- Geomodels of the GeoMol project: https://geomol.lfu.bayern.de/ (again hosted in Bavaria)

Some links you might find useful:

- <del>Original project: http://tu-freiberg.de/fakult3/gy/mageo/projekt_gst.html</del>
- spin-off which develops the database further: https://www.giga-infosystems.com
- Technology for displaying 3D in realtime: http://www.x3dom.org

**Edit**:
Disclaimer: I work for GiGa infosystems.